# Convert string to timestamp and get difference

Tags: sql, databricks

I am using the Databricks Community edition and trying to use SQL to get a date difference between two string values.
E.g. dates

```
col 1 date format - 11/22/2012 03:00:45 PM
col 2 date format - 11/22/2012
```

I have tried TIMESTAMP, to_timestamp(), and Timestampdiff but I get NULL values back. What's the best way to treat strings using time/date formats? I am also trying to pull just the year in some cases. I have experience with SQL but not sure where I am going wrong here.

Comment: So using those sample data, what are you expecting as the outcome? You want "difference" but didn't state the measurement.

Comment: sorry, I want a few outcomes 1/ measure the difference in seconds or minutes between two dates, 2/ query all the data between two dates. Right not both don't work or return NULL

Comment: How do single-digit months and days look in your data? Such as March 1st. And if the column does not have a time, then what exactly are you calculating? Should it be 00:00:00?

Comment: Dates are stored in some columns as 11/22/2012 and in other columns its a timestamp but stored as a string e.g. 11/22/2012 03:00:45 PM.

Comment: You'll need to use a `case expression` for both date columns to get them to appropriately cast to timestamp. `select case when len(start_date) > 10 then to_timestamp(start_date, 'MM/dd/yyyy h:m:s a')  else to_timestamp(start_date, 'MM/dd/yyyy') end as mod_start`. Repeat for 2nd date. Then write your datediff query against these correctly formatted columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your data are not consistent, you'll need to use `case expressions` for converting your strings to date/time formats (based on the length). Then wrap your query for your calculations. Or you can just do it all-in-one, but makes it more difficult to read.

```
select 
 mod_start, 
 mod_end, 
 datediff(SECOND, mod_start, mod_end) as seconds_diff, 
 datediff(MINUTE, mod_start, mod_end) as minutes_diff, 
 datediff(HOUR, mod_start, mod_end) as hours_diff 
from (
  with my_data as ( --cte with raw data
    select '11/22/2012 03:00:45 PM' as start_date, '11/22/2012' as end_date union all
    select '11/22/2012', '11/22/2012' union all
    select '11/22/2012', '11/23/2012' union all
    select '11/22/2012', '11/21/2013'
  )
  select --this query converts string dates/times to correct formats
   start_date, 
   end_date, 
   case 
    when len(start_date) > 10 then to_timestamp(start_date, 'MM/dd/yyyy h:m:s a')
    else to_timestamp(start_date, 'MM/dd/yyyy')
   end as mod_start, 
   case 
    when len(end_date) > 10 then to_timestamp(end_date, 'MM/dd/yyyy h:m:s a')
    else to_timestamp(end_date, 'MM/dd/yyyy') 
   end as mod_end
  from my_data
)z
--where mod_end < to_date('2012-12-31', 'yyyy-MM-dd') --uncomment if wanting to limit dates
```

| mod_start | mod_end | seconds_diff | minutes_diff | hours_diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2012-11-22T15:00:45.000+0000 | 2012-11-22T00:00:00.000+0000 | -54045 | -900 | -15 |
| 2012-11-22T00:00:00.000+0000 | 2012-11-22T00:00:00.000+0000 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2012-11-22T00:00:00.000+0000 | 2012-11-23T00:00:00.000+0000 | 86400 | 1440 | 24 |
| 2012-11-22T00:00:00.000+0000 | 2013-11-21T00:00:00.000+0000 | 31449600 | 524160 | 8736 |

Comment: I tried select
  to_timestamp(colname, 'MM/dd/yyyy') as date,
from
  schema but got an error, parkUpgradeException: [INCONSISTENT_BEHAVIOR_CROSS_VERSION.PARSE_DATETIME_BY_NEW_PARSER] You may get a different result due to the upgrading to Spark >= 3.0:
Caused by: DateTimeParseException: Text '1/31/2019' could not be parsed at index 0

Comment: And did you also try the answer I posted? Since you have some rows with and without a time, you need to use the case expression as I noted.

Comment: I tried casting it to 'm/d/yyyy' and that let the query run but the results were incorrect

Comment: I did, but the rows within a column are consistent with one format, its only the values in another column that are different. So col 1 is all mm/dd/yyyy and col 2 is mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss etc.

Comment: Well you really need to look at your data to see how dates are formatted. You originally inferred your dates were  in MM/DD format, but that error clearly shows January is presented as 1 (not 01). So you just need to confirm how Months (and days) are stored and adjust as needed. So instead of MM, try M for example. May also need to change DD to D.. again, depends on your data. Look up databricks timestamp patterns if you still have trouble.

Comment: Thanks! You are right, looks like the data is all over the place. In some places the month is 1 digit in some 2. Same for minutes and hours. What makes it even more complicated is that if I go by the length of the date its hard to say which digit is missing. Are there wildcard characters in Databricks? I can't see it in their data time format.

Comment: If you're seeing dates with multiple formats (01/01/2022 vs 1/01/2022 vs 1/1/2022) then that's a problem. Fix it further upstream in whichever system is collecting and storing it.

Comment: You could strip out leading zero and replace `/0' with '/'. Or just do some kind of replace on '0[0-9]/'. I don't know Databricks.

Comment: Apparently you have `try_cast()` available: https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/functions/try_cast.html

Comment: I resolved it. I manually edited the file and added leading and trailing zeroes where applicable to get the length of the string to be uniform. From there, I used @Isolated's comment on case/if/when statements to resolve the issue. Thanks all!